# how to get selected image path from grid view in Android studio

Tags: android, gridview

I want the path of the image selected from gridview and send it to another activity to apply filter on the selected image.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                currentImageViewId = v.getId();
                System.out.println("ID !!!!!!!!!!"+position);

                    Bitmap selectedPic =  SlideApplication.bitmapList.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(gridEditor.this, Photo_Effects.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imageUri", selectedPic.toString());
                    startActivityForResult(intent,Request_Code);
                    Toast.makeText(gridEditor.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
```

This code is just getting me view id.  I want the path of the selected image.

Comment: you can pass position in another activity and get bit map in that activity

Comment: Bitmaps have no paths. But you did put images in a gridview. Were they image files? You did not tell but of course you should have started telling us how you filled the gridview. And if you need a path then you should have someting like `String path  =  SlideApplication.pathList.get(position);`.

Comment: Bitmap selectedPic =  SlideApplication.bitmapList.get(position);   got bitmap using this.  problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform Bitmap to Uri or String before correctly.

Try this method:

```
public File bitmapToFile(Bitmap bit, String filename) {

    File f = new File(YourClassContext.getCacheDir(), filename);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();


        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = bit;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return f;

}
```

And then you get the Uri by `Uri file = Uri.fromFile(bitmapToFile(bitmap, name));`

Comment: Pretty cumbersome code. The only statement you would need in the try block: `bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,  new FileOutputStream(f));`

Answer (score 0):

how do you load this gridview? if you hold it in a hashmap or something like, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945794/gridview-click-gridview-item-to-show-image-in-imageview) solution